# SSH connection refused on azure vm

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine

I am able to render the public ip of a virtual machine on Chrome but not able to connect it with SSH, raising an error: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection refused. When I check the virtual machine on Portal, there is no security group assigned to it. Is that something to do with this? How can I fix it?

Comment: can you telent azure vm with port 22  from your local PC?

Comment: Not able to use telnet on windows 10. Http port is working, but not ssh port.

Comment: can't telnet azure VM or can't use telnet this command?

Comment: http work on port 80, SSH work on port 22, your VM create in classic VM or Azure resource VM?

Comment: Out of the box, every Linux VM you spin up in Azure has an ssh port open. If you used ARM, it'll be port 22. If you created a classic vm, it's either port 22 or a random port (if there is more than one vm in the `cloudapp.net` namespace. Perhaps edit your question with more details about the ports configured?

Comment: My VM is a docker vm.

Comment: Not a classic vm definitely.

Comment: connect to azure vm or the VM inside the docker?

Comment: Trying to install a docker container, so I am connecting to a docker vm.

Comment: I installed a new docker vm (vm with a docker extension), now the public dns is not working. Any idea about this?

Comment: Public DNS? do your mean FQDN, like xxx,cloudapp.com?

Comment: Yes, mypublicxxx.location.cloudapp.azure.com.

Comment: have you change other settings? or just install docker extension?

Comment: Nothing, I just followed the microsoft doc's guides using the existing template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140140/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-gene9y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, if we want to ssh to docker image, we should install SSH on this image, and open port for this image, I will run centos image for example:

```
docker pull centos:centos6
docker run -i -t centos:centos6
yum install openssh-server openssh-client(install ssh)
chkconfig sshd on
passwd(reset root password)
exit
docker commit 332b19ca916c centos/centosssh  (commit this image)

docker run -i -t -d -p 50001:22 centos/centosssh  (NAT for this container)
docker attach containerid  (connect this container)
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config  (modify sshd config)

change UsePAM to no

service sshd start
```

Then open port 50001 in Azure NSG.

This time, we can use SSH to connect it:

[image]

Update:

I use CLI 2.0 to create a VM with docker extension, and change public IP address to **static**, and use command `sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx` to run container on the VM. then use chrome to test the nginx, it works fine, and I can ssh to the Azure VM with **Public IP** and **FQDN**.
the nginx container:

```
jason@MyDockerVM:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
61e10ebb6d22        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   kind_leavitt
```

Try to use FQDN to ssh host:

```
[c:\~]$ ssh jason@mypublicdns.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com


Host 'mypublicdns.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com' resolved to 52.186.123.151.
Connecting to 52.186.123.151:22...
Connection established.
To escape to local shell, press 'Ctrl+Alt+]'.

Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-65-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Fri Apr  7 06:40:06 UTC 2017

  System load:  0.31              Processes:              118
  Usage of /:   5.8% of 28.80GB   Users logged in:        1
  Memory usage: 12%               IP address for eth0:    10.0.0.4
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
```

Try to use public IP address to ssh the host:

```
[c:\~]$ ssh jason@52.186.123.151
Connecting to 52.186.123.151:22...
Connection established.
To escape to local shell, press 'Ctrl+Alt+]'.

Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-65-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Fri Apr  7 06:40:55 UTC 2017

  System load:  0.21              Processes:              119
  Usage of /:   5.8% of 28.80GB   Users logged in:        1
  Memory usage: 12%               IP address for eth0:    10.0.0.4
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
```

Comment: I have update my answer, it work fine, please check it.

Comment: If you run docker image and still can't ssh to Azure VM, maybe we can try to use **reset ssh configuration**, we can find reset ssh config here, select VM-->reset password--->in the mode, select **Reset configuration only**.

Comment: So it is working. Then it should be working. Many thanks Jason

Comment: @Gene9y - if you have a new question, ask as a question. Not buried in comments.